# GitHub releases with generated files

Tags: github, yarnpkg, github-actions

I have a GitHub repo and would like to use GitHub Actions to create a release with a generated file included:

1. push a commit with a tag
2. the GitHub Action starts
3. it runs `yarn run build` (generates `dist/index.js`)
4. release is created that includes the `dist` folder

So far, I have not been able to do this. I've been able to use `"marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"` action to package the `dist` folder as an additional asset, but that's not it.

I want the `Source code (tar.gz)` in the GitHub release to contain the `dist` folder.

What I'm trying to do is use this generated asset as a `yarn` dependency, which works if I use the `Source Code (tar.gz)` but not if I use the additional generated asset.

[image]

Comment: GitHub has its own action for adding arbitrary files to a release, e.g. I use it in https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/a88aa8d1f76465ed4811b7f0670a5c27a34afe05/.github/workflows/push.yml#L91-L98. But you can't add things to the source code zip GitHub automatically creates - *that's the source code*.

Answer (score 1):

The entries your images show that are labeled “Source code (tar.gz)” and “Source code (zip)” are autogenerated from the contents of the repository and contain only and exactly what's in the repository.  They can't be modified in any way because they aren't persisted: they may be regenerated in the future.  That's also why they may change (so, for example, the hash of the contents need not be stable).

If you want to include additional dependencies in your tarball, simply upload your own source release that contains the generated files.  Many projects do this for various reasons, and you can do it, too.